# reverse a list manually using iterators(c++)

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have written a recursive function(somewhat ugly?) in c to reverse a singly linked list. It goes like -

```
struct node {
    int data; 
    node*next; 
};

node* reverse(node** current, node** newstart) {
    if( (*current) -> next == 0 )   {
        *newstart = *current;    //this is the new starting node
         return *current;
    }
    //as the recursion unwinds, we will get nodes in reverse order
    reverse( &((*current) -> next), newstart )-> next = *current;
    return *current;
}
```

How can I make a similar thing using iterators, something like this - ?

```
forward_list<int> :: iterator& reverseList(forward_list<int>& slist, forward_list<int> :: iterator& it) 
{
    if(it == slist.end())   return it;
...
}
```

I tried to see the code for reverse but couldn't decipher it. I know I can use a stack, or simply call reverse on forward_list , but I was wondering whether I can do such things with iterators? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just want to know how to implement a reversal with iterators, a bidirectional iterator would be much more convenient.

Comment: Why are you writing your own linked list when there is already a linked list which comes with a specialisation of the `reverse` algorithm?

Comment: Since you have a `std::forward_list` just call [`std::forward_list::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/reverse)

Comment: @NathanOliver, can someone tell me how the std::forward_list::reverse method is implemented or at-least tell me where to look?

Comment: @GauravSharma [This](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45918/in-place-reversal-of-a-singly-linked-list) should show you how it is done.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks. "And notice that that's how list reversal is implemented in STL". So they implement reversal in a similar way(iteratively rather than recursively). Just one more doubt. I know it would be discouraged, but can we manipulate iterators like node pointers and somehow write a function that I have mentioned in the question?